# Completely remove some strange iTunes-purchased songs

Tags: iphone, itunes

I do not understand why my iPhone recently gets some strange songs and I would like to delete them, completely.

To remove them, I first locate these songs in my iTunes library. But when I try to delete them, I get this message before continuing:

*`These items will be hidden from your iTunes purchases.`*

What I am looking for is a way to completely remove those songs. So simply hiding them from itune does not suffice. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: There is no delete - just hide. http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/30351/5472

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately their is no such way. For the U2 album Apple *forced* everyone to buy for free, there is a tool to completely remove it [SOI-Removal Tool](https://support.apple.com/de-de/HT201396)

The only option for your case would be to contact Apple Support in order for them to completely delete those purchases.