# Remove iOS apps from purchase history

Tags: ios, applications, ios-appstore, apple-id

I'm trying to remove apps I'll never use again from my purchase history.  Does anyone know how I might be able to do this? I don't want to just hide them, I want them gone. Realize same question was asked a few years ago which received a response that it's not possible.  Was hoping something has changed.  Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different. The way we handle duplicates is linking all the repeat questions to the main one, When the main question has wrong or outdated answers we use bounties and edits to update those questions. Any deviation from that can be discussed / arranged on [meta] - but the cases where a new question for the same problem is used is very rare and needs consensus from several people to move forward in practice. Don’t delete this - the duplicate helps search and people find the main thread. Thanks for re-upping this question - it is quite a popular one here.

Comment: Canonical question seems to be: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16100/deleting-itunes-app-store-purchases-from-my-account

Comment: Others include https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/16100/deleting-itunes-app-store-purchases-from-my-account

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to completely remove an app from your history. The closest you can get is deleting it and hiding it.

From [this Apple Discussion:](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/8040994)

> You can not nor do you need to. Apple wants you to have the app
>   available should you ever decide you have changed your mind. You can
>   hide it from the purchase list if it irritates you.